# Multi pickerView Crashes when selecting last array value from second pickerView?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Everything runs fine until I select the last item in the second UIpickerView. 
Any tips? if there are missing ending brackets just add some I doubt I left any, here is the code. Ps: Sorry if it looks a little sloppy

```
    class RegisterViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var Country: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView1: UIPickerView! //this is pickerView for Country


    @IBOutlet weak var Ethnicity: UILabel!   //this is pickerView for Ethnicity

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView2: UIPickerView!

   //country constant
    let country = ["United States", "China", "Japan", "Germany", "France", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Brazil", "Canada", "Spain", "Australia", "Sweden", "Mexico", "Russia", "Turkey", "New Zealand", "Ireland", "India", "Jamica", "Puerto Rico", "Hong Kong", "Russia"]

    //ethnicity constant
    let ethnicity = ["Black", "Causion", "Pacific Islander", "Indian", "Native American", "Middle Eastern", "Asian", "Russian", "Hispanic", "Irish", "German", "Jewish", "Mixed Race", "Other"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if pickerView1 == pickerView1 {
        return 1
    } else if pickerView2 == pickerView2 {
        return 1
    }
    return 1

    }

    func pickerView(_ _pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if (pickerView1 == pickerView1){
        return country.count
    }else if (pickerView2 == pickerView2){
        return ethnicity.count
    }
    return 1

    }
```

This looks like the problem area code. Xcode debug brings me here

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int,     forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if (pickerView == pickerView1){
        return country[row]
    }else if (pickerView == pickerView2){
        return ethnicity[row]
    }
    return ("")
    }

//view did load 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pickerView1.isHidden = false
    self.pickerView2.isHidden = false
   }
```

Comment: Add the crash log/error.

Comment: @Imad   
                 '0x105fe6e5c <+556>: movq   %rax, -0x38(%rbp)